# Remove inner nested string with RegEx

Tags: regex, vbscript, nested

I have a string that is formed from tag-substitution, which also results in parts of the string being marked for deletion, for example:

```
Keep1
{/*DELETE}
Delete1a
    {/*DELETE}
    Delete2
    {DELETE*/}
Delete1b
{DELETE*/}
Keep2
{/*DELETE}
Delete3
{DELETE*/}
Keep3
```

Am I correct that a RegEx cannot be used to select only the inner DELETE2 and DELETE3, remove those, and then repeat to get the DELETE1a/b until no further matches are found?

The RegEx I am passing to my replace function is

```
\{\/\*DELETE\}([\s\S]*?)\{DELETE\*\/\}
```

This matches

```
{/*DELETE}
Delete1a
    {/*DELETE}
    Delete2
    {DELETE*/}
```

If this is the only RegEx match that I can make I could [*suppress the leading* `{/*DELETE}` *and*] call the replace function recursively which, I think, would enable me to remove the nested {TAGS}

Is a better way?

I am using the RegEx in VBScript

**EDIT**: In case it helps I can change the `{/*DELETE}` and `{DELETE*/}` tags, even to a single character

**EDIT2**: I could use a single-character as the Start/End delete marker - if, for example, that would be faster for a RegEx expression to resolve e.g. by being less complex

e.g. if the Start-Delete is `[` and then end delete is `]`

```
Keep1
[
Delete1a
    [
    Delete2
    ]
Delete1b
]
Keep2
[
Delete3
]
Keep3
```

These characters chosen for appearance in this example, in practice they would occur within my real-world data, but I expect I could chose two ASCII values which do not appear in my data at all.

**Clarification**: The {DELETE} tags will not always appear on a line by themselves, so this style of string formation will also exist

```
Keep1{/*DELETE}Delete1a
    {/*DELETE}Delete2{DELETE*/}
Delete1b{DELETE*/}Keep2a
Keep2b{/*DELETE}Delete3{DELETE*/}Keep3
```

or with single-character delete-tags:

```
Keep1[Delete1a
    [Delete2]
Delete1b]Keep2a
Keep2b[Delete3]Keep3
```

Comment: Just please clarify: do you want to get `Keep1 Keep2 Keep3` in the end as three lines? What do you mean you can change the tags to single chars? It is not a good idea to use the same char for beginning/ending delimiters of a block, it is best to have a pair of different chars for the delimitation.

Comment: *Am I correct that a RegEx cannot be used to select only the inner DELETE2 and DELETE3, remove those, and then repeat to get the DELETE1a/b until no further matches are found?* That depends. There are edge cases where you can make it work with regular expressions, but not in general.

Comment: I know you can use this regex in other languages: `({/\*DELETE}(?:.*?(?1).*?|.*?){DELETE\*/})`, I'm unable to test for vbscript at the moment though.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - I was meaning to use different single characters for Start/End e.g. if excluding a single-character (in RegEx) was easier than trying to exclude a whole {TAG}

Comment: @Kristen Please add an example.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - clarification added. Do you think a single-character would allow a faster (i.e. less complex) RegEx expression? Good performance is a requirement for this code.

Comment: Of course it will be super quick - `\[[^\][]+\]`. But are you sure you can rely on the `[` and `]` to be absent from the data you need?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can assign the Open/Close single-character tag based on characters that are very unlikely to be present in the string, but also test for existence and if found then empirically find non-existing characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Multicharacter delimiters

If your delimiters are multicharacter tags, you may use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
\{\/\*DELETE}((?:(?!\{\/\*DELETE})[\s\S])*?)\{DELETE\*\/}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that will match any char, 0+ times, that is not a starting point for a `{/*DELETE}` char sequence.  Run this regex replace recursively, see [Iteration 1](https://regex101.com/r/OyeOBA/2) and [Iteration 2](https://regex101.com/r/z8lFuE/1) demos.

**NOTE** that if you have these delimiters inside comments or string literals, this won't work correctly.

To make it safe, you may define that the delimiting tags only appear as single entities on a line:

```
^\s*\{\/\*DELETE}(\s*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\{(?:\/\*DELETE|DELETE\*\/)}).*)*)\r?\n\s*\{DELETE\*\/}\s*$
```

See [Iteration 1](https://regex101.com/r/SgnXJt/1) and [Iteration](https://regex101.com/r/Zc1bG2/1) 2 demos (here, you will need to enable `regExp.Multiline = True`)

## Single char delimiters

This is by far the easiest scenario - you may the starting delimiter char, then match any 0+ chars other than the starting and ending delimiter char using a negated character class - and then the ending delimiter char.

If the starting delimiter char is `[` and the ending delimiter char is `]`, the regex is a well-known

```
\[[^\][]*\]
```

See the regex demo: [Iteration 1](https://regex101.com/r/zsry9d/3) and [Iteration 2](https://regex101.com/r/ORht3w/2).

Note that `[` and `]` usually are part of data you need, so perhaps, you will want to use some more fancy paired stuff, like `⦅` (*‎2985  LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS*) and `⦆` (‎*2986  RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS*):

```
\u2985[^\u2985\u2986]*\u2986
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zsry9d/2).

Comment: @Kristen I think you should use `⦅` and `⦆` to allow usual brackets in the data. Or check the Unicode table for weirder stuff :)

Comment: "fullwidth left white parenthesis" (U+FF5F) - never even knew that that was a thing let alone its cousins such as "left white tortoise shell bracket"! Thanks for that, looks ideal.